# Element <img> is not supported in <a>

Tags: xpath, telegram, xpath-2.0, instant-view

**Error:**

> An error has occurred while processing your template

**Code:**

```html
Element <img> is not supported in <a>: <img alt="" data-src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3351cc569871d023d58bcd1029b48437?s=26&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" class="avatar avatar-26 photo avatar-default" height="26" width="26"/>
```

Comment: Missing closing element of `<img>` may be problematic.

Comment: Where is that "template"? Where is the code that throws such an error? How is this related to Telegram?

Comment: https://github.com/olkitu/Telegram-Instant-View-Template-for-Wordpress I am using this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about you make `<a>` as `<div>`?

`<div>: //a[.//img]`

Answer (score 7):

You can split wrapped image into 2 separeted tags and Instant View will be generated:

```
@split_parent: //a/img
```

In your example it's just avatar, that must be removed, because Intant View requred only articles without any comments. You can delete it with that code and all be working fine:

```
@remove: //div[@class="someclass"]
```

Comment: First code splits wrapped image into 2 separated tags and IV (Instant View) will be generated correctly. The second code remove that content and IV will be generated) in example it's avatar and it must be removed. For more info, pls check contest manual ( yep, topic started want to win with help of others)

Comment: Please add all such information to the answer itself, not to the comment section. And what do you mean by that "contest manual"?